# How could I refactor this proc?

Tags: ruby

Alright. I have certain constraints. Mainly because this is just a small thing to a much larger application.

```
:vendor_username => Proc.new { |user|
  Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(user.id).username if Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(user)
}
```

This is the code I'm trying to refactor. Its proving to be a real pain in the ars.

The problem is is that this code is inside of a hash.

```
hash = {
  # proc here
}
```

I though up this:

```
hash = {}

if Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(user)
  hash[:vendor_username] = Proc.new { |user|
    Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(user.id).username
  }
end
```

Where all I'll have to do is add values inside the if statement, but it breaks. Its not possible to write it, even though I'd love to.

I need to refactor it because (a) it doesn't look nice and (b) there's going to be a LOT more values inside the hash.

Comment: (a) looks good enough except that you are calling `find_by_user_id` twice, use local variable, (b) doesn't make sense to me

Comment: How can I refactor `find_by_user_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
:vendor_username => Proc.new { |user|
  Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(user.id).username if Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(user)
}
```

The first problem was the if statement. I found this:

```
:vendor_username => Proc.new { |user|
  Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(user.id).try(:username)
}
```

But I'm still dependent on the DB. As @naomik points out: the `find_by_*` is deprecated, but is kept due to the fact that I'm on Rails 3.2.x. To remove this problem, I put it in a process and voila:

```
v = Proc.new { |current_user| Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(current_user) }

# and inside of the hash would be
:vendor_username => Proc.new { |user| v.call(user.id).try(:username) }
```

I spent hours trying to solve this problem. Can't believe its finally over.

BTW: I had a LOT of constraints. I did try (and was intent) on pumping the data in as @JCorcuera has shown. The code kept breaking and didn't understand who the current user was.

Answer (score 1):

```
def vendor_username(user)
  if vendor = Spree::Vendor.find_by_user_id(user.id)
    vendor.username
  end
end

hash[:vendor_username] = vendor_username(user)
```